# Small Straight - Method

Tags: java

I've been stuck on this method for a couple of days now. This method checks to see if the roll of 5 dice == a small straight. It works for some numbers. If I roll a

> 1, 2, 4, 3, 6

it will work. However, if I roll a

> 1, 2, 4, 3, 3

it will not work. I think it's because of the duplicate 3 in there. I need to move it to the end somehow.

A small straight is when there are four consecutive die face values, such as 1, 2, 3, 4 or 3, 4, 5, 6. It can be in any order such as 2, 3, 1, 4

```
      int counter = 0;
      int score = 0;
      boolean found = false;
      Arrays.sort(die);

      for (int i = 0; i < die.length - 1; i++)
      {
          if (counter == 3)
              found = true;

          if (die[i + 1] == die[i] + 1)
          {
              counter++;
          }
          else if (die[i + 1] == die[i])
          {
              continue;
          }
          else
          {
              counter = 0;
          }
      }

      if (found)
      {
         score = 30; 
      }
      else
      {
          score = 0;
      }
      return score;
    }
```

Comment: You've not defined a "small straight". Please be more explicit in your question.

Comment: Isn't a small straight 4 consecutive numbers? And a large straight is all 5?

Comment: Yes, I am really sorry. Can't think straight today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duplicate 3 is not what is throwing off the algorithm. The issue is that you check for the straight during the iteration AFTER it occurs. Thus, if the last die is part of the straight, it won't be recognized.

To fix this, move

```
if (counter == 3) found = true;
```

to the END of the loop. Should work.

EDIT: So it looks like this.

```
for (/*...*/) {
  /* Everything else */

  if (counter == 3) {
      found = true;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Castellanos Note that if you just move it to the end of the loop instead of copying it, now 12356 will not be a small straight - because the counter will be at 1 when the for loop ends, even though it was 3 earlier it didn't get 'noticed' when it was.

Comment: @Patashu Good point. Once you find the straight, you'll likely want to `break`. No sense looking at the other dice anyways, right?

Comment: @Castellanos Well, a better way to do it is to move the if counter == 3 (or 2) check to be the LAST thing in the for loop. That way it will run once after each pair of dice, including the last one. You don't need to run it before doing your first comparison, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: First, if a small straight is three in a row, then you want to see if the counter gets to 2, not to 3. 3 would demand a four in a row.

Edit the start of the for loop as follows:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < die.length ; i++)
  {
      if (counter == 2)
          found = true;
      if (i == die.length - 1) break;
      //method continues here
```

Reasoning: I imagine that when you started coding this method, it was throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s when it got to the last die in the array, tried to compare it to the nonexistant sixth die and died. So, you made the loop stop one short. But if it stops one short and the small straight is finished on the very last dice, then you never got into the loop again to confirm that the counter was 3 and a small straight had occured. By editing the start of the loop this way it goes all the way to the last element, checks and then breaks.

Alternatively, do one last check after the loop ends:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < die.length - 1; i++)
  {
      if (counter == 2)
          found = true;
      if (die[i + 1] == die[i] + 1)
      {
          counter++;
      }
      else if (die[i + 1] == die[i])
      {
          continue;
      }
      else
      {
          counter = 0;
      }
  }

  found = (counter == 2); // or counter >= 2 if you want larger straights to be found too

  //continue method here
```

Comment: This won't work for {1,2,3,6,7} for example. His logic is bad.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun Oh, I thought a small straight was four in a row. If it's three in a row, then I guess you check if counter == 2 rather than 3?

Comment: For `counter == 2` {1,2,2,4,2} will return 30 where it should be 0.

Comment: Yeah, I did mess up my logic. I apologize, and thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This should calculate the longest sequence:

```
int longestSequence(int[] a) {
  Arrays.sort(a);
  int longest = 0;
  int sequence = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    int d = a[i] - a[i - 1];
    switch (d) {
      case 0:
           // Ignore duplicates.
           break;
      case 1:
           sequence += 1;
           break;
      default:
           if (sequence > longest) {
             longest = sequence;
           }
           break;
    }
  }
  return Math.max(longest, sequence);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add code such as

```
for (int i = 0; i < (die.length-1); i++)
        {
            if (die [i] == die[i+1])
            {
                die[i+1] =1;
            }
        }
Arrays.sort(die);
```

This will set the code for example from 1,2,3,3,4 to 1,1,2,3,4 so your code should then work.